# How to properly format number real-time on <TextInput> in React Native?

Tags: javascript, android, node.js, react-native

```
<TextInput value={initialMoney} 
    onChangeText={(x) => {
      setInitialMoney(x.replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, '.'));
    }}
/>
```

The above code will not work correctly.

Instead of displaying 214.124.124.124

It will display 2.1.4.1.2.4.1.2.4.123

There is nothing wrong with the Regular Expression, I tried the regex outside the TextInput, and it works perfectly. Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

There might be some issues with your Regex. Try debugging it, I checked via [Regex101](https://regex101.com/) and it showed errors.
[image]

Try reading this post [How do you format a number to currency when using React native Expo?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55556221/how-do-you-format-a-number-to-currency-when-using-react-native-expo)

Hope this helps.